# Unable to find a suitable version for angular-translate

Tags: angular-translate

I use angular-translate in my app, and I install it with bower.
I have a problem of dependencies version in my bower.json

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "angular-translate": "2.2.0",
    "angular-translate-loader-partial": "2.0.0",
    "angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat" : "*",
    "angular-translate-handler-log" : "*"
},
```

I need "angular-translate": "2.2.0" to translate array of string (not available in 2.0.0), but angular-translate-loader-partial require "angular-translate": "2.0.0"

Each time I launch bower install, bower ask me wich version I want use (2.2.0 for my app or 2.0.0 for the partial loader)
I have the same problem with angular-translate-handler-log

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [current repository information](https://github.com/angular-translate/bower-angular-translate-loader-partial/blob/master/bower.json) the angular-translate version is setted to 2.2.x:

```
{
  "name": "angular-translate-loader-partial",
  "version": "2.0.1",
  "main": "./angular-translate-loader-partial.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-translate": "2.2.x"
  }
}
```

Be sure if you have your bower version updated:

```
npm update -g bower
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank for your response.
I set dependencies as:

```
    "dependencies": {
    "angular-translate": "2.2.x",
    "angular-translate-loader-static-files": "2.2.x",
    "angular-translate-loader-partial": "2.0.x",
    "angular-translate-interpolation-messageformat" : "2.1.x",
    "angular-translate-handler-log" : "2.0.x"
},
```